# Sed: append after last occurrence

Tags: sed

Let's say I have the following kind of file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preferences>
  <section id="widgets">
    <value id="version" xml:space="preserve">1</value>
  </section>
  <section id="wuid-b2a8e6b8-6619-714e-9cfe-466c27c90902">
    <value id="path to widget data" xml:space="preserve">{Preferences}widgets/opera-adblock-1.3.4-1.oex</value>
  </section>
  <section id="wuid-0c5cfdb2-8e51-f149-a1e7-51d66240ed7a">
    <value id="path to widget data" xml:space="preserve">{Preferences}widgets/flag-button-1.5.4-1.oex</value>
  </section>
</preferences>
```

My mission is to add text right after the last occurrence of `</section>`.

Looking at these two it seems as if utilizing `tac` would be simpler but I don't understand how to do that either: [Using sed to append a string to the fourth occurrence of a pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315959/using-sed-to-append-a-string-to-the-fourth-occurrence-of-a-pattern/9317095#9317095), http://www.unix.com/unix-dummies-questions-answers/46294-add-line-after-last-occurnace-pattern.html#post302149709

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you add it before the first occurrence of `</preferences>`?

Comment: @Blender, hmmmm, because I'm stupid. So how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to add things before the first occurrence of a string:

```sh
sed '/<\/preferences>/i\ADD SOME TEXT\nADD SOME MORE TEXT' file
```

Results:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preferences>
  <section id="widgets">
    <value id="version" xml:space="preserve">1</value>
  </section>
  <section id="wuid-b2a8e6b8-6619-714e-9cfe-466c27c90902">
    <value id="path to widget data" xml:space="preserve">{Preferences}widgets/opera-adblock-1.3.4-1.oex</value>
  </section>
  <section id="wuid-0c5cfdb2-8e51-f149-a1e7-51d66240ed7a">
    <value id="path to widget data" xml:space="preserve">{Preferences}widgets/flag-button-1.5.4-1.oex</value>
  </section>
    ADD SOME TEXT
    ADD SOME MORE TEXT
</preferences>
```

You can read more about how to insert a line before a string [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-41). HTH.

Comment: This is incorrect. The new text has to come on a completely new line.

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE: It does. Did you _actually_ follow the example?

Comment: Yep. `sed: 1: "/<\/preferences>/i\ADD  ...": extra characters after \ at the end of i command`

Comment: Ahhah. Turns out, gnu `sed` is less anal about this rule than the `sed` on Mac OS X. That said, it *is* described that way in both the manual pages for gnu `sed` *and* OS X `sed`; it is both officially required and more portable to have the contents on a new line.

Answer (score 6):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```sh
sed '/\/section/{x;/./p;x;h;d};x;/./!{x;b};x;H;$!d;x;s/\/section[^\n]*\n/&  HELLO\n/' file
```

In essence: on encountering a line containing `/section` start storing all remaining lines to the end of the file in the hold space (HS). If lines are already in the hold space and another such line is encountered print the lines in the HS and begin storing lines again. At the end of the file insert the desired string and print out the stored lines.

Comment: Thank you. Everybody else was solving the OP’s problem, which is of course very useful for them and most of the point of the site. You are the only person who answered the question asked (and you still posted a solution which would help the OP), which helps the people like me who came from Google with similar questions.

Answer (score 2):

To insert text after the last section tag, i.e. before the ending "preferences" tag:

```
sed 's#</preferences>#  HELLO\n&#' file.xml
```

The output looks like this:

```
...
  </section>
  HELLO
</preferences>
```

To do it in place use the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i 's#</preferences>#  HELLO\n&#' file.xml
```

To do it as a pipe:

```
cat file.xml | ...whatever... | sed 's#</preferences>#  HELLO\n&#'
```

Heads up that using `sed` and regular expressions on XML tends to lead to problems because XML isn't regexp-based nor line-based. To do it better, use a real XML parser in perl, python, ruby, java, etc.

Comment: `cat file.xml | sed` is a useless use of `cat` : `sed` can read `file.xml` directly

Comment: @sputnick good point; i'll clarify that in my answer. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One way :

```
sed -i 's@</preferences>@  <section id="x">\n   <value id="path to widget data" xml:space="preserve">{Preferences}widgets/xxxx</value>\n  </section>\n&@' file.xml
```

This snippet add a new `<section>` in the `XML` file.

### RESULT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<preferences>
  <section id="widgets">
    <value id="version" xml:space="preserve">1</value>
  </section>
  <section id="wuid-b2a8e6b8-6619-714e-9cfe-466c27c90902">
    <value id="path to widget data" xml:space="preserve">{Preferences}widgets/opera-adblock-1.3.4-1.oex</value>
  </section>
  <section id="wuid-0c5cfdb2-8e51-f149-a1e7-51d66240ed7a">
    <value id="path to widget data" xml:space="preserve">{Preferences}widgets/flag-button-1.5.4-1.oex</value>
  </section>
  <section id="x">
   <value id="path to widget data" xml:space="preserve">{Preferences}widgets/xxxx</value>
  </section>
</preferences>
```

Comment: Instead of writing `</preferences>` twice, why don't you just group the pattern or use the `&` symbol like joelparkerhenderson has done? It would make reading your one-liner slightly easier on the eyes.

Answer (score 1):

with awk you can do like this

```
awk '$0 ~ /<\/pref/{print "Hello\n"$0}' temp.txt
```

output

```
Hello
</preferences>
```

Comment: cant get it to work. 
`awk '$0 ~ /#include/{print "#include <dt-bindings/zmk/bt.h>\n#include <dt-bindings/zmk/mouse.h>\n"$0}' temp.txt`
Outputs
`#include <dt-bindings/zmk/bt.h>
#include <dt-bindings/zmk/mouse.h>
#include <dt-bindings/zmk/keys.h>`
which is wrong order and it doesnt update the file

Answer (score 1):

[@Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751863/steve)'s answer above is the right way to go about this, but it contains a quirk that causes it to fail on OS X. The proper, portable way to encode multi-line insertion `sed` scripts is to:

1. Precede the actual content with a newline,
2. Escape each newline (including the first one, after the command) with a backslash.

Here's an updated example, given the text in your initial post:

```
sed -i '' '/<\/preferences>/i\
ADD SOME TEXT\
ADD SOME MORE TEXT\
' test.xml
```

---

For reference, excerpts from [the OS X `sed(1)` manpage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html),

```
     [2addr]H
             Append a newline character followed by the contents of the pattern space to the hold space.

     [1addr]i\
     text    Write text to the standard output.

     [2addr]l
             (The letter ell.)  Write the pattern space to the standard output in a visually unambiguous
```

… and from the [GNU `sed(1)` manpage](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?sed):

```
       text   Append text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a back-
          slash.

       i \

       text   Insert text, which has each embedded newline preceded by a back-
          slash.

       q      Immediately  quit  the  sed  script  without processing any more
          input, except that if auto-print is  not  disabled  the  current
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my method when I am going to add a line after last `#include`.

```
grep -n '#include' $file | tail -1 | cut -f1 -d: | xargs -I % echo %+1 | bc | 
xargs -I '{}' sed -i '{}i// clang-format off' $file
```

- Get line number of last occurrence and add 1 to it.
- Use sed to insert a line at the line.